# Versioning routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Do I need to create different controllers for each API versions?

Ex. I have route named `v1.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'as' => 'v1.'], function () {
    Route::get('me', [API\UserController::class, 'getUserInfo'])->name('me');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts', 'as' => 'posts.'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [API\PostController::class, 'list'])->name('list');
        Route::post('/', [API\PostController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    });
});
```

If I have a new version of API `v2.php` should I use the same controllers from API? What's best practice?

Comment: DRY might help you... if some endpoints have not changed between v1 and v2, then makes no sense to copy paste the code

Comment: "have not changed" also means the pre-conditions and the post-conditions, by which i means like authentication, independence to other endpoints, data and so on

Answer (score 0):

in App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider
you find  boot function

```
 public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```

you can add prefix as you like and separate files for example

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')
                    ->middleware('api')
                    ->group(base_path('routes/api1.php'));

Route::prefix('api/v2')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->group(base_path('routes/api2.php'));
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I've already wrote in my question about separate files.

Comment: it's the best way,I think, and can organize your code clearly

Comment: I’m asking about controllers. Do I separate them for each api version files.

Comment: for me, I use this method : API\V1\   API\V2